# How to combine 2 splines from different spline container in unity spline 2.3.0?

Tags: unity, c#, windows, splines

I'm working on with Unity Spline 2.3.0, I realize that the splines cannot be touch and combine with other splines that exits in different spline container.

Is there any way to connect them?

I tried to copy component but it doesn't work.

The reason is that I made the spline become a prefab.

For example, i made a prefab which is a splineContainer, that prefab have a spline 0 with 2 knots. The point is when i made 2 or more object with that prefab, while copy component, the index of 2 knots become exactly the copy one, so it literally just replace the older, i want to make 2 spline with the same shape and connect them, not make 2 spline at the same position(which of course cannot be connected).

[image]

Like this, i want to connect spline a.0 to spline b.0

Help me find a way please, Im so upset after 4 days with no solution (T.T).

Comment: If the last 2-3 control points of one spline are identical to the first 2-3 control points of the next, the splines should connect smoothly in space. How many control points you need to match depends on the type of spline in use.

Comment: Thank you but no. I mean the spline must be spawn unexpectedly, that's why i made Spline prefabs. The 1 prefab = 1 spline container. What i want is connect 1 spline from 1 prefab to another 1 spline from another 1 prefab

Comment: Why should a.0 connect to b.0? a.x should be the same as b.0